# What is the gradient of $x^T A\, x$ with respect to the matrix $A$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I have seen many times that the gradient of $x^TA\,x$ with respect to $x$ is $2A\,x$. But how do you find its gradient with respect to $A$?

Answer (score 2):

You can just write
$$
f(A)=x^TA\,x= \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_i x_j
$$
Therefore
$${\partial f \over \partial a_{ij}}=x_i x_j$$
and the gradient is the matrix with entries $(\nabla f)_{ij}=x_i x_j$, that is
$$
\nabla f = x\,x^T.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is consistent with what I was trying to prove. Thank you!